# Cohort analysis in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to do some cohort analysis on a userbase.  We have 2 tables "users" and "sessions", where users and sessions both have a "created_at" field.  I'm looking to formulate a query that yields a 7 by 7 table of numbers (with some blanks) that shows me: a count of users who were created on a particular day who also have a session created y = (0..6 days ago), indicating that he returned on that day.

```
created_at  d2  d3  d4
today       *   *   *
today-1     49  *   *
today-2     45  30  *
today-3     47  48  18
...
```

In this case, 47 users who were created on today-3 returned on today-2.

Can I perform this in a single MySQL query?  I can perform the queries individually like so, but it'd be really nice to have it all in one query.

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`os` = 'ios' AND (`sessions`.`updated_at` BETWEEN '2013-01-16 08:00:00' AND '2013-01-17 08:00:00')
```

Comment: So, a day begins/ends at 8am?

Comment: "users who were created on x = (0.. **6** days ago) who also have a session created y = (0.. **7** days ago)" – did you mean to put the same number of days in both cases? Or is the final part of that sentence ("indicating that he returned on that day") supposed to explain how a session can be created before the user is (I don't really get it, sorry)?

Comment: Thanks Andriy, sorry I found this problem a little hard to explain.  It was a typo on my part.  They were both supposed to be 0..6.

Answer (score 23):

This seems a complex problem. Regardless of whether it also seems to you a difficult one or not, it is never a bad idea to start working it up from a smaller problem.

You could start, for instance, with a query returning all the users (just the users) that have been registered within the last week, i.e. starting from the day six days from now, as per your requirement:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

The next step could be grouping the results by dates and counting rows in every group:

```
SELECT
  created_at,
  COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY created_at
```

If `created_at` is a `datetime` or `timestamp`, use `DATE(created_at)` as the grouping criterion:

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS created_at,
  COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

However, you don't seem to want *absolute* dates in the output, but only *relative* ones, like `today`, `today - 1 day` etc. In that case, you could use the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function, which returns the number of days between two dates, to produce (numeric) offsets from today and group by those values:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_at) AS created_at,
  COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Your `created_at` column would contain "dates" like `0`, `1` and so on till `6`. Converting them into `today`, `today-1` etc. is trivial and you will see that in the final query. So far, however, we've reached the point at which we need to take one step back (or, perhaps, it's rather a half step to the right), because we don't really need to count the users but rather their *returns*. So, the actual working dataset from `users` that is needed at the moment will be this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_at) AS day_offset
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

We need user IDs to join this rowset to (the one that will be derived from) `sessions` and we need `day_offset` as the grouping criterion.

Moving on, a similar transformation will need to be performed on the `sessions` table, and I won't go into details on that. Suffice it to say that the resulting query will be very identical to the last one, with just two exception:

- `id` gets replaced with `user_id`;
- DISTINCT is applied to the entire subset.

The reason for DISTINCT is to return no more than one row per user & day: it is my understanding that however many sessions a user might have on a particular day, you want to count them as *one return*. So, here's what gets derived from `sessions`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_id,
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_at) AS day_offset
FROM sessions
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Now it only remains to join the two derived tables, apply grouping and use conditional aggregation to get the required results:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('today', IFNULL(CONCAT('-', NULLIF(u.DayOffset, 0)), '')) AS created_at,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 0) AS d0,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 1) AS d1,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 2) AS d2,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 3) AS d3,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 4) AS d4,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 5) AS d5,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 6) AS d6
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_at) AS DayOffset
  FROM users
  WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created_at) AS DayOffset
  FROM sessions
  WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) s
ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.DayOffset
;
```

I must admit that I haven't tested/debugged this, but, if this be needed, I'll be happy to work with the data samples you will have provided, once you have provided them. :)

Comment: How do we modify this query for a monthly cohort?

Comment: @user160108: By changing the interval and increasing the number of output columns accordingly, perhaps? I'm not sure, I must admit. Would have to take some time to look into this deeper to remember the problem properly, and I don't have that time at the moment, to be honest. Sorry.

Comment: @AndriyM thanks. how can I perform this thing within a date range given by user? .

Comment: @Andrain: I'm not sure what you mean and whether a comment box will provide me enough space for an answer. Asking a new question with an example and explanation is likely a better course of action. You can link to this question and/or answer if you think it will help people to understand your problem better.

Comment: @AndriyM Sir please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324457/how-to-build-dynamic-cohort-analysis-on-weekly-basis

Comment: this is invalid answer, you are summing ALL users who had session at certain date not users who registered

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the feedback, though I'm not sure I understand the issue. I'm selecting the users registered within the last seven days (more specifically, "today" and the previous six days), then finding all their sessions within within the same period. Is there a problem with this part of the logic? Or is the problem with the implementation? Where do you believe I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> ***Example Of Month Wise Cohort:***

**First Let's Create Table Individual User Activity Flow (MONTH WISE):**

```
SELECT 
    mu.created_timestamp AS cohort
    , mu.id AS user_id
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 1 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m1
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 2 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m2
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 3 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m3
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 4 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m4
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 5 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m5
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 6 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m6
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 7 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m7
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 8 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m8
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 9 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m9
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 10 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m10
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 11 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m11
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 12 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m12
FROM user mu 
WHERE mu.created_timestamp BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
```

**Then After This Table Calculate the individual activity-sum of the user:**

```
SELECT MONTH(c.cohort) AS cohort
       ,COUNT(c.user_id) AS signups
       ,SUM(c.m1) AS m1 
       ,SUM(c.m2) AS m2 
       ,SUM(c.m3) AS m3 
       ,SUM(c.m4) AS m4 
       ,SUM(c.m5) AS m5 
       ,SUM(c.m6) AS m6 
       ,SUM(c.m7) AS m7 
       ,SUM(c.m8) AS m8 
       ,SUM(c.m9) AS m9 
       ,SUM(c.m10) AS m10 
       ,SUM(c.m11) AS m11 
       ,SUM(c.m12) AS m12 
FROM (SELECT 
    mu.created_timestamp AS cohort
    , mu.id AS user_id
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 1 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m1
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 2 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m2
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 3 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m3
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 4 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m4
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 5 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m5
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 6 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m6
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 7 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m7
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 8 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m8
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 9 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m9
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 10 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m10
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 11 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m11
    ,(SELECT IF(COUNT(l.order_date) = 0 , 0, 1) FROM order l WHERE MONTH(l.order_date) = 12 AND l.user_id = mu.id) AS m12
FROM user mu 
WHERE mu.created_timestamp BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59') AS c GROUP BY MONTH(cohort)
```

**In replacement of months you can use days, other wise cohort analysis mostly use in month cases**

Answer (score 2):

This answer inverts the output table that @Newy wanted so the cohorts are the rows instead of the columns, and uses absolute dates instead of relative ones.

I was looking for a query that would give me something like this:

```
Date        d0  d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6
2016-11-03  3   1   0   0   0   0   0
2016-11-04  4   2   0   1   0   0   *
2016-11-05  7   0   1   1   0   *   *
2016-11-06  7   3   1   1   *   *   *
2016-11-07  13  5   1   *   *   *   *
2016-11-08  4   0   *   *   *   *   *
2016-11-09  1   *   *   *   *   *   *
```

I was looking for the number of users that signed up a certain date, then how many of those users returned 1 day later, 2 days later, etc.  So on 2016-11-07 13 users signed up and had a session, then 5 of those users came back 1 day later, then one user came back 2 days later, etc.

I took the first subquery of @Andriy M's large query and modified it to give me the date a user signed up, not the days relative to the current date:

```
SELECT
    id,
    DATE(created_at) AS DayOffset
  FROM users
  WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Then the LEFT JOIN subquery I modified to look like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    sessions.user_id,
    DATEDIFF(sessions.created_at, user.created_at) AS DayOffset
    FROM sessions
    LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = sessions.user_id)
    WHERE sessions.created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

I wanted the dayoffset not relative to the current date as in @Andriy M's answer, but relative to the date the user signed up.  So I did left join on the user table to get the time the user signed up and did a date diff on that.

So the final query looks something like this:

```
SELECT u.DayOffset as Date,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 0) AS d0,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 1) AS d1,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 2) AS d2,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 3) AS d3,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 4) AS d4,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 5) AS d5,
  SUM(s.DayOffset = 6) AS d6
FROM (
 SELECT
    id,
    DATE(created_at) AS DayOffset
  FROM users
  WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) as u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    sessions.user_id,
    DATEDIFF(sessions.created_at, user.created_at) AS DayOffset
    FROM sessions
    LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = sessions.user_id)
    WHERE sessions.created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) as s
ON s.user = u.id
GROUP BY u.DayOffset
```

Comment: Could you please check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324457/how-to-build-dynamic-cohort-analysis-on-weekly-basis

Comment: Could please say me how to do same for week and monthly retention in mysql?

Comment: Here's a Q and A for weekly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521587/how-can-i-create-a-weekly-cohort-analysis-table-using-mysql/47521588#47521588  I'll work on a monthly one sometime this week.

Answer (score 0):

Monthly cohort based on @Newy response:

```
SELECT u.MonthOffset AS MONTH,

  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 0) AS m0,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 1) AS m1,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 2) AS m2,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 3) AS m3,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 4) AS m4,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 5) AS m5,
  SUM(s.MonthOffset = 6) AS m6
FROM (
 SELECT
    id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, DATE(date), CURDATE()) AS MonthOffset
  FROM users
  WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 month
) AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, DATE(date), CURDATE()) AS MonthOffset
    FROM sessions
    WHERE sessions.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 month
) AS s
ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.MonthOffset;
```