# SQL for cohort analysis report (window function?)

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I was playing around with Cohort Analysis in Google Analytics and was trying to figure out how to write it in SQL. There is a pretty extensive answer to this from about 5 years ago for MySQL here: [Cohort analysis in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452538/cohort-analysis-in-sql). However, I was wondering if with the new `window` functions in mysql8, this might have gotten significantly more easy. For example, to reproduce this:

[image]

I would assume the data is something like:

- timestamp
- user_id
- user_creation_timestamp

And it seems like the date interval is per week over the past 6 weeks. Does the window/partitioning functions make this any easier now?

Comment: Looks more like a pivot to me, and the lead answer uses conditional aggregation which is a pivoting technique. Window functions don't necessarily make pivoting any easier as far as I'm aware; ultimately a pivot is turning a lot of rows and a few columns into fewer rows and more columns, whereas window functions essentially perform grouping/aggregation on a DataSet but don't affect the row count. You could use window functions in a pivot, probably to augment the original data set with extra columns of info that is aggregate in some specific way but it doesn't make pivoting any easier or harder

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question* -- preferably with a SQL/db fiddle.  A question should stand on its own.